# MDB not persisting data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, jpa, weblogic12c

I have MDB configured to receive incoming message and persist it via a SLSB using JPA (eclipseLink). The database inserts work for one off message but in load conditions (3 or 4 messages per second),  Data is not persisted in DB. I can see sql Insert queries in the log but no data in DB.
Persistence File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <!-- <persistence-unit name="mainPU" transaction-type="JTA"> -->
    <persistence-unit name="mainPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>ecpcPool</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.Address</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.Customer</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.DocumentationSignature</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.EcpSystem</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.EcpTransaction</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.EcpWkflw</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.EidVerify</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.EsignDetail</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.Finpln</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.FinplnDocumentation</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.ThirdPartyCrdntl</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.ThirdPartyDocumentation</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.TransactionType</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.Advice</class>
        <class>com.fc.ECP.domain.Advcln</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="WebLogic_10" 
/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" 
value="ecpcPool" />
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" 
value="jdbc/MicrosoftSQLServer"/> -->
            <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" 
value="ecp_prx_ds"/> -->
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database"

value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.SQLServerPlatform" />
            <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" 
value="com.fc.adr.jpa.JPASessionCustomizer" />
            <property name="com.fc.adr.jpa.schema" value="$(mainPU.schema)" 
/>
            <property name="com.fc.adr.jpa.schema.sequences" 
value="$(mainPU.schema.sequences)" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" 
value="DefaultLogger" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
            <property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode" 
value="commit" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to EJB2 style config for MDB.
Underlying Cause:
The EJB3 style MDB ‘s methods are wrapped by CDI injection.
 One of the wrapper classes in the stack trace is: com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext 
which is in a spring framework module jar in weblogic
 MethodInvocationInvocationContext looks for a WebServiceContext in the JNDI tree at “java:comp/WebServiceContext”
Having a jax-ws service puts a WebServiceContext at “java:comp/WebServiceContext”
If the WebServiceContext is present, then MethodInvocationInvocationContext tries to access its values for the MessageDrivenContext
The spec requires WebServiceContext to throw an IllegalStateException if it is accessed outside of a web service call